# Is there a way to have tooltips feature in Python/Streamlit plotly graph, to explain the graph legends and axis labels

Tags: python, plotly, streamlit

I am trying to include the tooltip feature in plotly graph on a streamlit web app. Is there any way to have tooltips appear when I hover over each legend color and axis labels?

[image: at these circled areas]

Comment: There is a click event on legend, but not hover.